# System.ArgumentNullException error in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I wrote some code in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBqxcb).

I do not understand where I made the mistake which returns a compilation error. Please have a look at the url I gave and guide me.

### My code

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.HomeController

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    </head>

    <body>

<form id='your-form' action='@Url.Action("Index","HomeController")' method='post'>
     <b>Gender</b><br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male' /> Male <br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Female' /> Female <br />
     <hr />
     <b>Hobbies</b><br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Reading' /> Reading <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Sports' /> Sports <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Movies' /> Movies <br />
     <input type='submit' value='Update Profile' />
</form> 
    </body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string gender, string[] hobbies)
        {
            // Example output 
            var output = String.Format("The user's gender is <b>{0}</b> and they enjoy <b>{1}</b>", gender, String.Join(",", hobbies));
            return Content(output);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used dotnetfiddle much, but the error doesn't appear to be coming from your code, specifically. I added a basic model, and then the error went away:

```
namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class Foo
    {
    }
}
```

It appears that dotnetfiddle requires *something* to be in the model section.

Also, in addition to the problem noted by @AndreiM, you've also set your view model to be your controller in the view. That's not right. If you have no model, then just remove the model declaration line.

Comment: when i post the after select gender and hobbies then nothing happen but in action there is code which return to show posted data. can u tell me why this happen?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that would cause a completely blank page to be returned on post. However, at this point, as in the previous, you might simply be debugging dotnetfiddle rather than your own code. It's a neat idea, but it is, at the end of the day, a website trying to dynamically piece together an MVC app, compile it, and proxy back a result to your browser. It's never going to be perfect. Just create a local MVC project and run your code in Visual Studio. Then, you'll truly know that its your code and not some third-party website causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some code in 'Model' frame of fiddle.

```
public class Test{}
```

it will compile then.